# OpenCV VdeoWriter problems - RGB columns in the video

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I'm trying to do some video processing but can't figure out how to output the result. I need an RGB video. When I write code like this, I expect the output to be a white 200x100 rectangle:

```
oy = 100
ox = 200
wri = cv2.VideoWriter("output/vid.avi", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG"), 30.0, (ox, oy))

testarr = np.empty((oy, ox, 3))
testarr.fill(255.0)

for i in range(500):
    wri.write(testarr)
```

But instead, I get this:

[image]

I tried using `MJPG`(they say it's the safest option), `XVID`, `DIVX` and changing the video format, everything is the same.

I don't even know which part causes the problem: should I be looking for a different codec? or maybe I'm using wrong array structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working in `4.0.0`. Therefore I redefine the `testarr` variable as:

```py
testarr = np.empty((oy, ox, 3), dtype="uint8")
```

Then white background video appears.

You can use `.avi` with `MJPG` code as stated [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/22/writing-to-video-with-opencv/)

But if you are planning to use `XVID` or `DIVX` you need to initialize your code to `MP4V`